# Xcode6 Beta6 - Unknown class SCNView in Interface Builder file

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

I created a new Swift project and made a couple of changes according to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1) as follows:

1. Modified the `GameViewController.swift` as shown in the tutorial.
2. Created `GameScene.swift` as shown in the tutorial.

*NOTE: I am not listing the source code here verbatim as I believe it has no part in this error, but I'll gladly do so if anyone thinks otherwise.*

Then I should be able to just compile and run the project to load a background image. Instead, I get the following error message during compilation.
[image]
[image]

I noticed there are some variations of this kind of error on SO, and I tried the following suggestions with no success:

- iOS Simulator (Menu) -> Reset Content and Settings -> Reset
- Window -> Organizer -> (Select my project) Delete Derived Data
- Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Selected Xcode 6.0 (6A280e) for Command Line Tools

What else can I do to get past the error? More importantly, perhaps, what's causing this error in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you chose SceneKit when creating your project from the template, instead of SpriteKit as the tutorial specifies.

Comment: You're certainly right! Kinda embarrassing but I chose the wrong option and it never crossed my mind to be the culprit. Do you mind telling me how you were able to pinpoint the problem?